# On AWS S3, can I exclude a file from lifecycle rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket that has a short lifecycle rule, everything older than 7 days gets deleted. The files that are added have dynamically generated names.

There is one file in the bucket that I would like to exclude from this rule, is there a way to exclude this file from the rule so it is never deleted?

Comment: If your file name that need to be deleted has a certain prefix that is different from the one you wish not to be deleted, then you can define lifecycle rule based on the prefix.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is not a way to exclude objects from rules that match them.  Most likely, you will need to rearrange your objects using prefixes that meet your needs.

There is a hack... which would involve copying the file into itself frequently enough that it never ages enough to match the rule, but that is obviously delicate.  The S3 PUT+Copy operation does allow an object to be copied on top of itself non-destructively without downloading and re-uploading, and this would reset the expiration timer.

But most likely a better solution is to prefix your random filenames with a few static characters.  The S3 partition splitting implementation (the way S3 handles bucket capacity scaling) can apparently work just as well with with a static prefix (e.g. `images/`) followed by random characters as it can with entirely random keys.

Comment: Thanks, for this system altering the file naming strategy would be a breaking change. The hack solution actually sounds pretty good though, I can probably add a scheduled lambda function to do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is small enough so that it doesn't matter to pay for Glacier and S3 storage, you could also initiate a restore and set `Days` to a very high number.

Answer (score 1):

Hey a bit late but I found an alternative solution that may work.

You can implement **Object Lock** S3 property. When you turn on Object Lock for a bucket, the bucket can store protected objects, it means that these specific objects can't be deleted from the bucket for a specific period of time.

Object Lock seems to have precedence above Lifecycle.

Here is the reference: [AWS Object Lock Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/object-lock-overview.html#object-lock-retention-periods)