# Amazon AWS S3 Lifecycle rule exception?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-glacier

I've got a few s3 buckets that I'm using as a storage backend for Duplicacy which stores its metadata in chunks right alongside the backup data.

I current have a lifecycle rule to move all objects with the prefix "chunks/" to Glacier Deep Archive. The problem is, I then can't list the contents of a backup revision because some of those chunks have backup metadata in them that's needed to list, initiate a restore, etc...

The question is, is there a method where I could apply some tag to certain objects such then, even though they are in the "chunks/" folder, the are exempt from the lifecycle rule?

Answer (score 0):

Looking for solution to basically the same problem.

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46202309/on-aws-s3-can-i-exclude-a-file-from-lifecycle-rule) which seems consistent with what I'm finding which is it can't be done in a straightforward fashion. This is a few years old, I'll be disappointed if this is the answer.

Expected to see the exclude use case in [these examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html) but no luck.

Comment: sounds more like a comment and less like an answer

Comment: Correct. Stack refused my comment so I tried to add to the pursuit of an answer the only way it allowed. Happy to delete when something better surfaces.